# Not able to install ipa file via itunes to iphone 6(xcode is 7.2)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I used to create the IPA file from Xcode/Product/Archive and install it via iTunes. Recent Xcode version is 7.2 and iphone6 OS version is 9.3.1 when i add IPA file, the app keep on showing 'installing' in iTunes and disappears the installing icon on iPhone after loading but never completed. I Know that when i update my Xcode fix this problem. but after update my Xcode the swift syntax will change or not.

Any solution to fix it.

Comment: Can you try installing it using XCode->Devices->SelectYourDevice. Click on the add button on the bottom and select your IPA for installation.

Comment: @ArunGupta i tried to install through xcode.. which i can install only 9.2 under version Os. iphone 6 is 9,3.1 which cannot install. Let me try once more.. :)

Comment: I think you are right.. Xcode won't even detect the device mostly as it doesnot have the 9.3.1 SDKimage.  What you can do is install Xcode 7.3 also, you can keep both version of Xcode. Don't open your project in Xcode 7.3 but install the IPA using devices in Xcode7.3.

Comment: @ArunGupta ohh... how can make a IPA file without opening the project. ?. i want to change the deployment target right.. ?.

Comment: Deployment target would be the lowest you are support. Is your application will only be running on 9.3+ devices. You can generate the IPA using 7.2 and install on device using 7.3. Other option is usin TestFlight.

Comment: @ArunGupta thankz arun. actually i need to send IPA file to my client to check the project. i send one IPA file. which is not installed. They are using higher version so that i cannot do anything. For the client need what i want to say to client :)

Comment: Version should not be an issue, there are apps on App Store which don't get  updated for ages still they get installed on higher version devices. Check for few things. 1. Ask them to delete the current app and reinstall the new one. 2. Update the version number of your app and regenerate the IPA. 3. If its for testing purpose then generate the IPA with new profiles.

Comment: @ArunGupta How can we keep both Xcode ?.. weather i want to rename it. now i download Xcode 7.3 dmg file... but i don't open it..

Comment: @ArunGupta After your advise only i keep my next foot... so i am waiting for your reply. :)

Comment: Let me try it out myself on my system. I had done it many number of times. When you install the XCode it will ask you if you want to keep both version or replace it with newer. Let me download and get back to you.

Comment: @ArunGupta ya sir i keep both version. now i have both. but my doubt is how can i install ipa file in Xcode 7.3 ?...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110098/discussion-between-arun-gupta-and-sreezzz).

Comment: @ArunGupta Sir i install the app using Xcode 7.3 after that what i want to do ?...